# OpenCV - detect if image contains one or more objects of focus

Tags: opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I'm attempting to classify images into two types:

1. Type 1 : If an image contains a central object of attention / focus
2. Type 2 : Or if an image is more 'background-like' - containing many objects / patterns and not a single object of attention / focus.

Example of Type 1:

[image: Example of #1 above]

Example of Type 2:

[image: Example of #2 above]

What should be my approach using OpenCV?

I intend to build an approach that I can run through large number of images.

Comment: Google for "visual saliency"

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways it could be done, each method would work in some images and not others, but a simple method would be to detect edges in the image (eg: using Canny edge detector) then count how many pixels are edge pixels in the centre region of the image and compare that number to the number of edge pixels in the corner regions of the image.